# Bootstrap modal carousel displays current carousel item rather than the first item

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-modal

- I would like to always see the **1st item** when I click to open this bootstrap modal carousel.
- If I open the modal and carousel to a slide, it will remain on that slide the next time I open the modal.

---

**Example scenario:**

1. Open modal
2. Carousel to *3rd item*
3. Close modal
4. Open modal again
5. *3rd item* is shown

---

How can I make sure that the **1st item** is always shown upon opening the modal?

I've tried various ways of assigning `class="active"` with JQuery but haven't had any success.

#### Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dankreiger/pngybtc3/)

---

The code you'll find in the demo:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper"> 
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="open-modal-button" data-target=".mymodal" data-toggle="modal">Open Me</a>
        </div>
    <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade mymodal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                     <h3>1st item</h3>
                                    <button aria-label="Close" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close Window</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                     <h3>2nd item</h3>
                                    <button aria-label="Close" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close Window</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                     <h3>3rd item</h3>
                                    <button aria-label="Close" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close Window</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                     <h3>4th item</h3> 
                                    <button aria-label="Close" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close Window</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#carousel" role="button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#carousel" role="button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You can use `show.bs.modal` event to do something before modal is shown, [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).
2.And use `.carousel(number)` to go particular slide number in bootstrap [Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-methods).

use this JS

```
$('.mymodal').on('show.bs.modal',function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel(0)
})
```