# Bootstrap Modal, dynamic content load

Tags: html

i am passing the value of 1 to the modal input box but it wont display it

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" class="Add-Dialog" data-id="1" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> </span>
```

**Modal**`

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
     <input type="text" name="help" id="help" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".Add-Dialog", function () {
     var myHelpId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #help").val( myHelpId );
});
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32556451/3465753) might help you. Upvote if helped.

Comment: Heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1013/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="modal-content" id="myModal"> <!--Add modal id-->
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
     <input type="text" name="help" id="help" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **`Then in js`**

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var span = $(event.relatedTarget) // Span that triggered the modal
  var myHelpId = span.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes

  $(this).find("#help").val( myHelpId );
})
```

See this example http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target for more details